# Adding a custom icon to product prices

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have created a 'Latest Products' row, within the Homepage of a WooCommerce enabled WordPress Website.  What I would like to achieve now, is to insert an icon, on either side of the price entry.

I am aware on how I can add `<i class="fa fa-circle fa-rotate-270" aria-hidden="true"></i>` through hard coding directly into the web file, however I have used a WooCommerce shortcode to call such products and thus I am not sure how I can now achieve this.  The shortcode I am using is:  `[recent_products per_page="4" columns="4"]`

Would I need to make an entry into the **`functions.php`** file?

Any help on this matter, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple ways to do it, and here you get 2 of them…

1) The most easier way (assuming that is for simple products) is to use a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_price_html`** filter hook to display around your products prices this icon:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_html', 'prepend_append_icon_to_price', 10, 2 );
function prepend_append_icon_to_price( $price, $instance ) {
    // For home page only and simple products
    if(is_front_page()){
        // Your icon
        $icon = ' <i class="fa fa-circle fa-rotate-270" aria-hidden="true"></i> ';
        // Prepending and appending your icon around the price.
        $price = $icon . $price . $icon;
    }
    return $price;
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

---

2) you can also use a custom function hooked in **`wp_footer`** action hook to inject with jQuery your icons arround the prices:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'prepend_append_icon_to_price' );
function prepend_append_icon_to_price() {
    if(is_front_page()){
    ?>
        <script>
            (function($){
                var myIcon = ' <i class="fa fa-circle fa-rotate-270" aria-hidden="true"></i> ';
                $('.home .woocommerce .price').prepend( myIcon ).append( myIcon );
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec.  Your 1st suggestion worked perfectly fine.  As a side question, could placing the relevant WooCommerce php file (from the WooCommerce Plugin) into the theme folder and then editing the file accordingly, be another option or is this considered not good practice?

Comment: Excellent.  Pretty much what I was thinking, so thanks for the added insight.  A Vote Up is on its way! :-)